# What does the deferred option mean in NGINXs listen directive?

Tags: nginx

I've seen example NGINX configurations with the "deferred" option added to the listen directive

```
server { 
  listen 80 default deferred;
  ... 
}
```

I can't work out what it does (and whether or not I should use it) and the documentation doesn't make too much sense to me

> deferred -- indicates to use that postponed accept(2) on Linux with
>   the aid of option TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT

Can anyone explain what this option is for?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT can help boost performance by reducing the amount of preliminary formalities that happen between the server and client.

You can read more about it [HERE](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/take-advantage-of-tcp-ip-options-to-optimize-data-transmission/).

Comment: Basically though, I'll suggest giving it a miss.

Comment: FYI "deferred" is Linux-only. For example on FreeBSD it won't work.

Comment: Link is broken, try this: https://web.archive.org/web/20130521025331/http://www.techrepublic.com/article/take-advantage-of-tcpip-options-to-optimize-data-transmission/1050771

Comment: Seems like link moved here http://www.techrepublic.com/article/take-advantage-of-tcp-ip-options-to-optimize-data-transmission/

Comment: Is this still relevant in 2017?

Comment: @PKHunter probably so - according to @oleg2tor suggested updated link, `TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT` is a technique to boost performance for streaming data.